# AngularJS [$rootScope:infdig] error with Random Number function

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a  [$rootScope:infdig] error but my code actually works.  What I am trying to do is load an image or a random placeholder image if one does not exist.

```
<div ng-repeat="v in tiles track by $index" id="text-{{v.ID}}" class="lity-hide row-fluid lityBox">
            <div class="span3">
                <img ng-src="{{v.Image !== undefined ? v.Image.split(',')[0] : getPlaceholderImg() }}">
                <h4 class="centerMe">{{v.Title}}</h4>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Here is the function in $scope:

```
$scope.getPlaceholderImg = function() { 
        $scope.placeholderImg = "http://myurl.com/defaultImg" + Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1) + ".jpg";
        return $scope.placeholderImg;
    }
```

Comment: Fairly certain the problem lies with the conditional interpolation expression bound to `ng-src`. AngularJS tries to determine when models have stabilised, but if the references keep changing (as in your case possibly), it results in an infinite digest (i.e. cannot stabilise). So, rather than invoke `getPlaceholderImg()`, try have something else set `$scope.placeholderImg` beforehand and use the latter as the second part of the ternary instead.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the one-time binding operator (`::`) to stabilize the expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="v in tiles track by $index" id="text-{{v.ID}}" class="lity-hide row-fluid lityBox">
    <div class="span3">
        ̶<̶i̶m̶g̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶r̶c̶=̶"̶{̶{̶v̶.̶I̶m̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶!̶=̶=̶ ̶u̶n̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶?̶ ̶v̶.̶I̶m̶a̶g̶e̶.̶s̶p̶l̶i̶t̶(̶'̶,̶'̶)̶[̶0̶]̶ ̶:̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶P̶l̶a̶c̶e̶h̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶I̶m̶g̶(̶)̶ ̶}̶}̶"̶>̶
        <img ng-src="{{::v.Image !== undefined ? v.Image.split(',')[0] : getPlaceholderImg() }}">
        <h4 class="centerMe">{{v.Title}}</h4>
    </div>              
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - One-Time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)
- [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:infdig
  Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).